# Nested center and vertical alignment

Tags: html, css

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/e4b3kd3k/14/)

**Goal:**

I have a container and a circular subject container which will have subject details.

**Problem:**

Subject div is not horizontally center

**CSS**

```
.user_body_content_container
{
 display: table;  
}

.subject_container  
 {
 width: 200px;
 height: 250px;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}

.subject
{
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 1px solid #653;
 width: 175px;
 height: 175px;
 margin: auto; 
 position: relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}

.subject div
{ 

}
.subject .subject_completion
{

}
```

I don't want the solution alone and I think this design is horrible. Can you please tell me if you find any problems with my design

Comment: now link is working thanx.

Comment: You can't use margin with table-cell

Comment: you need subject and 55% in one line or 55% is under subject?

Comment: did not get you? in one line or under?

Comment: percentage should be Under the subject @Leothelion

Comment: ok working..ty for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one approach that allows you vertical align your subject without padding, margin and tables. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbt4vspr/9/)

The basic idea is using `:before` (or `:after`) and `display: inline-block` elements like the following:

```
.subject:before {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.subject_data {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;    
 }

 <div class="subject">
     <div class="subject_data">
        <div class="subject_name">Subject</div>
        <div class="subject_completion">55%</div>                
     </div>
 </div>
```

The approach above is cross-browser because pseudo-elements `:before`, `:after` supported among all [browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent).

Comment: Nice solution. Let me understand it. Can you please explain how did u use pseudo elements here in plain english

Comment: Vertical aligning works well with `inline-block` sibling elements. But in your case we need to add one `pseudo-element` to simulate sibling for simulation of second sibling. Using pseudo-elements allows don't change markup.

Comment: This worked great for me.  Take care that if your parent elements are using 'line-height' it will mess up your centering , so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution:

```
.subject
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #653;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 66px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**UPD:** Here's another one: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcv90v0n/)

HTML

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="inner-table">
        <div class="circle">  
          <div class="subject_name">Subject</div>
          <div class="subject_completion">55%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 10%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.inner-table {
    display: table;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
}
.circle {
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #653;
    overflow:hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**UPD 2:** One more: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czahk3sb/)

HTML

```
<div class="rectangle">
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="name">Subject</div>
    <div class="load">55%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rectangle {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 37px 13px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.circle {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**UPD 3:** Shorter version

```
.rectangle {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    border-spacing: 12px 37px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Comment: sorry but by padding-top, you can't make word align as it will reflect that's why we have vertical-align middle etc. Please avoid using that much padding. Thanx

Comment: I don't prefer this static padding. it will affect my design with different brwosers

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming css3 and don't have to worry about browser compatibility,
here is a simple solution:

UPDATED

```css
.user_body_content_container {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.subject_container
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 250px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.subject {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.subject_name
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.subject_completion {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="user_body_content_container">
    <div class="subject_container" id="subject_container0" index="0">
        <div class="subject" index= "0">
            <div class="subject_name">Subject</div>
            <div class="subject_completion">55%</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this ,  [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e4b3kd3k/17/)

```
<div class="subject_name">
    Subject
    <span class="subject_completion">55%</span>
</div>

.subject_name span{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Yes. But that circle is not horizontally center of the rectangle

Comment: Do we need to keep this html structure ?

Comment: Your suggestion is corret. You are free to change anything. But the thing I am trying to make is a rectangle, circle centered inside that retangle, subject details centered inside the circle. Clear?